# TableAdapter.update() and Identity Column

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

this code On form load event

```
dataGridView1.DataSource= DataTable1TableBindingsource
```

User will enter the data using dataGridView1,
and following code used to update rows in DataBase

```
Dim My_Datatable_Added As DataTable = DataSet1.DataTable1.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)
If My_Datatable_Added Is Nothing = False Then
   For Each My_Data_Row As DataRow In My_Datatable_Added.Rows
      Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Update(My_Data_Row)
   Next
End If
```

it is working fine and inserting rows in Database,

but the Datatable1 has an Identity Column set with auto (-1,-2,-3 etc) , and that column not show the real Identity value on DataGridView1 after inserting

if used the following code

```
Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Update(DataSet1.DataTable1)
```

everything works fine because here is using the following query after inserting rows in same scope:

```
Select * from Datatable1 where (Column1_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

but due to some conditions needs to go to first option

Is there any way to show the Identity value as on database on DataGridView if we use Update(DataRow) instead of Update(DataTable) and how to use the SCOPE_IDENTITY()?

thanks for all in advance

Comment: *"due to some conditions needs to go to first option"*. What conditions?

Comment: Is it because you want to save new records but not updates or deletes? If there is a valid reason, you still don't need a loop. `GetChanges` returns a `DataTable` and you can just pass that to `Update`. That `DataTable` will then contain the auto-generated IDs, so you'd need to `Merge` that with the original `Datatable`.

Comment: thanks sir, in fact still need loop for many points here, other way , could return the Identity value for specific row after inserting ? even show (-1) on datagridview?

Comment: So you're refusing to answer my question then? Maybe you're doing the right thing but those of us who have been around for a while no just how often people don't do the right thing, so some of us like to check first. If you can't explain why you're doing something then I can only assume that you have no good reason for doing, so I won't waste my time helping you do it.

Comment: thanks sir, for help, the matter is will take a lot of time to explain and I thought that will waste your time which is not related to the subject, again many thanks

Comment: Perhaps you might want to read up using SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(), ExecuteScaler() and ExecuteNonQuery().  While tableadapters are quite powerful, sometimes it can help to use these methods where you can get a little more manual control.  Eg, running multiple sql statements in one command, one being a query to select SCOPE_IDENTITY() to return the newly inserted PK value

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the SetField method to update the data;

```
DataTable vehicle = dataSource.Tables[0];
vehicle.Rows[this.currentRow].SetField(3, "Updating the 4th column in the grid");
vehicle.Rows[this.currentRow].SetField(2, "Updating the 3rd column in the grid");
```

Comment: Yes thanks sir, let us take this customer table as example, that code insert row and return identity that is ok, but the datagridview.datasource bind to CustomersBindingSource, after inserting row still datagridview not show the identity in database until fill data again, that is why need insert process and select  SCOPE_IDENTITY() run in same scope,

Comment: I modified my answer.